# extract rows of a datetime dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, range

i have this following Datetime dataframe that i have set the datetime column as my index

Datetime                 ratio                     dif

2022-06-09 12:33:00 -0.3861241598107547 -299.50183804712964

2022-06-09 12:34:00 -0.360130489922861  -274.88184087028105

2022-06-09 12:35:00 -0.22108950904852795    -166.02672464097395

2022-06-09 12:36:00 -0.18316426991752388    -135.2928226604197

2022-06-09 12:37:00 -0.09932437001820388    -72.14644129886278

2022-06-09 12:38:00 -0.0820362738010348 -58.58522049972339

2022-06-09 12:39:00 -0.04310125282586597    -30.25449340858836

2022-06-09 12:40:00 -0.48650055935157194    -335.5773828284086

2022-06-09 12:41:00 -0.040251923613339506   -27.620467464237436

i want to select specific rows of the dataframe in order to make a new one
i tried the following

df2 = frames.loc[frames["Datetime"].between('2022-06-09 12:34:00','2022-06-09 12:38:00' )]

and the ouput is

File "C:\Users\spain\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3631, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Datetime'
could anybody help me ?

Comment: The column `Datetime` doesn't exist. Check if you have empty spaces in that string, e.g. `Datetime ` or ` Datetime`

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt exist ?

Comment: You tried to do `frames["Datetime"]`, right? However, there is no column named "Datetime" in your dataframe. You might have "Datetime " (i.e. with a trailing space at the end). Or "Datetime\t" (i.e. with a trailing `tab` character). Something like that. `pandas` is very literal, so if you have an invisible character there in your column name, you won't be able to access it.

Comment: i have no empty spaces inside the datetime .

Comment: i have set the datetime column as my index

Comment: how can i extract the rows between two indexes i want ?

Comment: Ah, if it's the index, then you shouldn't do `frames["Datetime"]`. Instead, do `frames.index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# set column Datetime as index (if not already)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df = df.sort_values(by='Datetime').set_index('Datetime')
```

and then you can filter your dataframe:

```
print(df['2023-03-03 12:34:00':'2023-03-03 12:38:00'])
```

Prints:

```
                        ratio         dif
Datetime                                 
2023-03-03 12:34:00 -0.360130 -274.881841
2023-03-03 12:35:00 -0.221090 -166.026725
2023-03-03 12:36:00 -0.183164 -135.292823
2023-03-03 12:37:00 -0.099324  -72.146441
2023-03-03 12:38:00 -0.082036  -58.585220
```